# Why the difference in Dart SDK library modules?

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart

I've downloaded a project from GitHub, and in the Android Studio External Libraries it shows 21 library modules. These correspond nicely with the directories in my C:\src\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\lib directory.

However, if I create a new app from scratch, using File>New>New Flutter Project... Flutter Application, the External Libraries only shows 11 library modules.

I can't see any difference in the Project Structure between the two projects. Why the difference?

[image: Created from scratch][image: Downloaded from Github]

Answer (score 0):

Look at the `pubspec.yaml`. That is the place where people in Flutter declare their dependencies. It is likely that your downloaded project has some dependencies that your newly created one does not have. Also the Flutter version may matter.

You can paste the two `pubspec.yaml`s here if you do not see why the difference in yaml results in differences in libraries.

Comment: The environment and dev_dependencies sections are exactly the same. The dependencies for my project has "cupertino_icons: ^1.0.0" .  Am I right in thinking that the items shown in the External Libraries>Dart SDK part of the Project pane should reflect the contents of the C:\src\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\lib ?

Comment: @user3012629 Actually IMHO that it just what ide wants to show you. it does not necessarily show what the flutter project actually contains.